# Django Rest Framework - Can't avoid null fields being serialized in response

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

A simplified example of my issue:

I have this class:

```
class PropertySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
     class Meta:
            model = Properties

            fields = (
                'key',
                'value'
            )
```

I'm serializing a `ManyToManyField` field in a model leading to `Properties`. It has only one record. This is what I'm getting (which is correct, I put a `null` value there on purpose):

```
properties": [
      {
        "key": "test_property",
        "value": null,
      }
    ]
```

This is accurate, but I'd like to *filter out* all `null` `value` fields.

So far everything I tried failed. Still getting the null value serialized out. I tried:

1. setting `blank=False` on the value field in the `Properties` Model.
2. adding `value  = serializers.CharField(allow_null=False)` to `PropertySerializer`
3. adding `extra_kwargs = {'value': {'allow_null': False}}` to `PropertySerializer`

Then I discovered this:

```
class NoNullModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        result = super(serializers.ModelSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        return OrderedDict([(key, result[key]) for key in result if result[key] is not None])
```

If my serializer class derives from this, it will remove all null values. However, I would still like to know if there's a per-field setting that actually works and I've missed in the framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [**DRF core arguments**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#core-arguments) are used to validate the input data while [**deserialization**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#deserializing-objects) process. In your case, DRF serializers are [**serializing the data**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#serializing-objects) from your model instance/QuerySet. During the *serialization*, DRF won't validate the data since coz, it thinks that they are already validated.

---

#### workaround

```
class PropertySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    fields_to_be_removed = ['value']

    class Meta:
        model = Properties

        fields = ('key', 'value')

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        rep = super().to_representation(instance)
        for field in self.fields_to_be_removed:
            try:
                if rep[field] is None:  # checks if value is 'None', this is different from "emptiness"
                    rep.pop(field)
            except KeyError:
                pass
        return rep
```

Comment: this is the best null blocker

Comment: Null Blocker works like a charm. Thanks!